# How to persist class toggling across sessions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, session

I am using key shortcut to class toggling like below.

```
// Toggle admin bar using Tab + q
key('tab + q', function(){
  $('body').toggleClass('admin')
});
```

But I would like to store that across sessions. How will be the best way to do that?

I tried use jQuery.cookie.js

```
// Toggle admin bar using Tab + q
if ($.cookie('adminBarVisible') == 'false') {
  $('body').removeClass('admin')
};

key('tab + q', function(){
  if ($.cookie('adminBarVisible') == 'true') {
    $('body').removeClass('admin')
    $.cookie('adminBarVisible', false)
  } else {
    $('body').addClass('admin')
    $.cookie('adminBarVisible', true)
  };
});
```

But on refresh for a while (0.5sec) I see admin bar on top.

Comment: Client side, use cookie or local storage variable that will store current status for specific user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either:

- cookies - most cross-browser solution, utilize `document.cookie` (or any other cookie javascript plugin out there) to access cookie value in condition when checking if something should be toggled initially. There would be additional value when using cookies, since cookies are send to your server with every request, hence making themselfs available for server side use.
- [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Storage) - easy to use, available on newer browsers, data is persisted accross sessions.

Comment: I used ``jquery.cookie.js``: https://gist.github.com/37a11f3e1b94ec74c6fb but I dont like way how I remove class in line ``3``

Comment: What do you mean you don't like it? Duplication of `removeClass` code? If so, abstract that to other function with something like this https://gist.github.com/4267418 And if you control (on server side) if the admin class gets added to body, then check (when generating the page) the value of *adminBarVisible* cookie, that way you can remove code from lines 2 to 4 (from your gist).